# Sort object by category and name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in jQuery or javascript to sort the data by category in descending order and name in ascending order?

I have tried to sort the data twice similar to the sample code below, but it's not working as it should be.

The data should be listed by category like B, A and will sort next by name like AA, AB, BB and so on.

Sample data and sort script:

```js
var data = {
  0: {
    category: 'A',
    name: 'AA'
  },
  1: {
    category: 'B',
    name: 'BB'
  },
  2: {
    category: 'A',
    name: 'AB'
  },
  3: {
    category: 'A',
    name: 'BB'
  }
}

var items = $( $.map( data, function ( val, i ) {
  return val;
} ) );

// Sort data by category in DESC order.
function sortByCategoryDescOrder( a, b ) {
  if ( a.category < b.category ) {
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a.category > b.category ) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function sortByNameAscOrder( a, b ) {
  if ( a.name < b.name ) {
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a.name > b.name ) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

items.sort(sortByCategoryDescOrder);
items.sort(sortByNameAscOrder);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The expected output should be:

```js
var data = {
  0: {
    category: 'B',
    name: 'BB'
  },
  1: {
    category: 'A',
    name: 'AA'
  },
  2: {
    category: 'A',
    name: 'AB'
  },
  3: {
    category: 'A',
    name: 'BB'
  }
}
```

Comment: This should help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/sort

Comment: or any of these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+sort+object+multiple+properties

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```js
let data = {
  0: {
    category: 'A',
    name: 'AA'
  },
  1: {
    category: 'B',
    name: 'BB'
  },
  2: {
    category: 'A',
    name: 'AB'
  },
  3: {
    category: 'A',
    name: 'BB'
  }
}

let result=Object.values(data).sort((a,b)=>{
    if (a.category>b.category){
     return -1;
  } else {
    if (a.category<b.category){
         return 1;
    } else {
       if (a.name > b.name) {
         return 1
       } else {
          if (a.name < b.name) {
            return -1
          }
       }
    
    }
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Two issues.

- Your `sortByCategoryDescOrder` sort return values are incorrect. Descending order sort should return +1 when `a < b`, -1 when `a > b` and 0 on `a === b`.
- `sortByNameAscOrder` function, shouldnot compare objects with
  different `category`. You have already sorted the array based on `category`, if you again sort the array by comparing different `category` value, it will give you the soeted format of original array. You should return `0` for different `category` values, which means you are not changing order in that case.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
var data = {
    0: {
        category: 'A',
        name: 'AA'
    },
    1: {
        category: 'B',
        name: 'BB'
    },
    2: {
        category: 'A',
        name: 'AB'
    },
    3: {
        category: 'A',
        name: 'BB'
    }
}

var items = $($.map(data, function (val, i) {
    return val;
}));

// Sort data by category in DESC order.
function sortByCategoryDescOrder(a, b) {
    if (a.category < b.category) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.category > b.category) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

function sortByNameAscOrder(a, b) {
    if(a.category !== b.category) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

console.log(items.sort(sortByCategoryDescOrder));
console.log(items.sort(sortByNameAscOrder));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Second sort will completely undo the first one. This is not how to sort by multiple properties

Comment: @charlietfl it will never. Please check the output of the fiddle.

Comment: You don't sort an array twice. Second sort does not know about the first criteria.

Comment: @SalmanA Please check the code for second sort, there I specifically bypass `a.category !== b.category` this will leave nodes with different category un oriented